# the second if block does not work in django template file

Tags: django, templates, if-statement

In views.py:

```
all_pages = 5
```

In html file:

```
{% if all_pages > 2 %}
    <a href='...'>next</a>|<a href='...'>prev</a>
{% endif %}

{% if all_pages = page %}
    <a href='...'>prev</a>
{% endif %}
```

But when I'm in 5th page, still both `<a>` tags appear.

Why the second `if` block does not work?

And how can I fix it?

============ for updating my question =========

in views.py:

```
def main(request):
    list = PMenu.objects.all()
    kol = request.META['PATH_INFO']
    kol = kol[6:]
    mylist = kol.split('-')
    os = mylist[0]
    sh = mylist[1]
    en_chest_name = mylist[2]
    cc = mylist[3]
    page = mylist[4]
    next_page = int(page) + 1
    prev_page = int(page) - 1
    senf = PDivContent.objects.get(id=cc)
    #########################################################
    users = PUser.objects.filter(ostan=os, shahr=sh, content_id=187)
    #########################################################
    all_users = 20 
    all_pages = math.ceil(all_users/4)
    one = type(all_pages)
    two = type(page)
    #########################################################
    And return part goes here...
```

In main.html:

```
current page: {{ page }}<br>
all users: {{ all_users }}<br>
all pages: {{ all_pages }}<br>
content_id: {{ cc }}<br>
next page: {{ next_page }}<br>
type of all_pages: {{ one }}<br>   #output => 0
type of page: {{ two }}            #output => was empty
<hr>



{% if all_pages == 1 %}
    there is only one page
{% elif all_pages > 1 and page == '1' %}
    <a href='/main/{{ os }}-{{ sh }}-{{ en_chest_name }}-{{ cc }}-{{ next_page }}'>next</a>
{% elif all_pages > 1 and page == all_pages %}
    this is the last page
{% else %}
    <a href='/main/{{ os }}-{{ sh }}-{{ en_chest_name }}-{{ cc }}-{{ next_page }}'>next</a>|<a href='/main/{{ os }}-{{ sh }}-{{ en_chest_name }}-{{ cc }}-{{ prev_page }}'>prev</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I guess you have a syntax problem, change the second if like: `{% if all_pages == page %}`

Comment: I tried that but did not work.

Comment: Syntax should be like that for sure. There might be some problems in the `views.py` as well. so you may want to include it in your question.

Comment: Well, the function in views.py is long, but the problem is in an other place I think. It is not possible to use this `{% if all_pages == page %}`, it is not possible to compare 2 variables in django template if condition. And also `{% if page == all_pages %}` does not work eather.

Comment: You might not pass page argument to template or `page` and `all_pages` are not same type. But can't say for sure if we don't see the code. Your only error in this template code is missed `==` .

Comment: It's definitely possible to compare two variables in an `if` statement. check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators @niloofar

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: `page` seems to be a string here not an `int` while `all_pages` is int. So you can not compare them. Also I would suggest to pass your variables as url arguments, instead of your current approach. it will be much cleaner and faster.

Comment: Yes you are right. `page` variable was not int. I changed it to int and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @sheshkovsky, could you please make your suggestion a little more clear for me? I didn't understand it well. `I would suggest to pass your variables as url arguments, instead of your current approach.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112754/discussion-between-sheshkovsky-and-niloofar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page` seems to be a string type here not an integer while `all_pages` is integer. So you can not compare them. 
Also I would suggest to pass your variables as url arguments, instead of your current approach, it will be much cleaner and faster.